# Geofencing Alert Analytics - Impossible?

Tags: iphone, ios, analytics, geofencing

I work on the IT side of things in my company and I'm currently working on a project with an iOS developer. The project is basically an app which will notify the user of in-store offers with an alert when they enter a 250m radius geofenced area. There are currently 160 of these geofenced areas.

My company would love to have some data concerning how many alerts are being sent within each geofenced area per day/week/month (whatever we can get!) to assess which areas users are most active in.

I have been told by the developer that this is in fact impossible. I would really appreciate some guidance as to if this is possible and where I can find more information, i.e. are there any mobile analytics services that provide this?

I have been trying my best for the past 4 days to find more information about this, with limited success. I would really appreciate some guidance.

Answer (score 0):

**This is possible, but something else is impossible - tracking simultaneously 160 geolocations. This will drain battery life, and indeed the maximum number of geolocation that one app can track simultaneously is around 20.** (this is an iOS limitation and there is no workaround or "hack" around it)

This is indeed, very well possible. I'll try to explain it on a high level of abstraction.

In order to notify your user, your app is notified from iOS that the user entered or exited a certain area.

And that's your chance to send a query to add new row in an database (somewhere online, on your server, etc), containing the date the notification fired and from what geo area it has been fired.

And this is it, pretty trivial.

You should however think about how you should design your database, and what you should store inside it.

Answer (score 0):

Tell your "Developer" to throw in a tiny little piece of code into his tiny little app which writes a tiny little record in the database every time said app records either and entrance or an exit event and which region triggered it.

Here is the code, if he tries to tell you its impossible again:

```
- (void)exited:(CLRegion *)region //could also use entered
{
    NSString *id = [NSString stringWithFormat:[region identifier]]; //id of region triggered in app
    NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"id=%@",id]; //append id to data which you post to server so it can record it in your database
    NSString *hostStr = @"https://www.yourwebsite.com/yourapp/ios_data.php?"; //actual url of your webpage which will write data to database for you
    hostStr = [hostStr stringByAppendingString:post]; //put two and two together
    NSData *dataURL =  [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: [ NSURL URLWithString: hostStr ]]; // package them
    NSString *serverOutput = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataURL encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding]; //read response from server (your own output confirming record)
}
```

Questions?